# Auto update Google Map from database

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, google-maps

I have a MySQL database populated with latitude and longitude.

The data is plotted like a polyline on Google Maps.
Everything is working, but i don't know how to auto update the polyline when there is new data added.

I've tried to set interval on the function initmap, but that did not work.
I would appriciate if someone could help me with this.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <style>
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

   function initMap() {
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(59.913063,10.750923),
      zoom: 10,
      mapTypeId : 'terrain'
    });

    var flightPlanCoordinates = [
        <?php
            require("dbcred.php");
            $connection = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $database);

            mysqli_select_db($connection, $database);
            $query = mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT latitude, longitude FROM geografi");
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){
                $lat = $row['latitude'];
                $lon = $row['longitude'];
                echo 'new google.maps.LatLng('.$lat.', '.$lon.'),';
            }
        ?>
    ];


   var flightPath = new google.maps.Polyline({
       path: flightPlanCoordinates,
       geodesic: true,
       strokeColor: '#FF0000',
       strokeOpacity: 1.0,
       strokeWeight: 2
       });
       flightPath.setMap(map);
   }

    </script>
    <script async defer src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=GoogleKey&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: You need to use Ajax request with interval.
If you can separate js code from php code it will be better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution how to do it.

First i did like suggested by Ahmad - put the php in a different file, and made a ajax call. The ajax returned latitude and longitude.

Then I made a function that removed the existing polylines.
After that, I made a update function, that was called by ajax.

In the end, I made a interval function that called the remove function and the update function, by a set interval.

Answer (score 0):

Have you taught about reloading the page to give you the desired effect, by adding Jquery to your code you could use this function, this will reload your browser every ten seconds, alternatively, you could call your own method instead, maybe initialize the map again reloading all the new data.

```
new PeriodicalExecuter(function(pe) {
    location.reload(true);
}, 10);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I tried that. The only thing that i want to change, is the polyline. If I update the whole map every time, it will be too much.

Comment: I wonder could you keep calling,  flightPath.setMap(map); or maybe make an update function that will call Database method and the method to draw your poly-line, keep running this periodically